# How is it possible that the same IP is shared between different domains?

Tags: ip

I have a web service used by some websites. In my log file I found that there is 5 websites (different domains) who send post requests to my web service with the same IP address.

How is it possible ? I'm wondering if there is a way to distinguishing this websites ?

Note : To get the user IP I use this PHP code :

```
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually five different websites using your service, it's one server which happens to host five different websites. Your service is used by servers, not by websites. To differentiate between them, you would have to require the websites to provide their names in a custom HTTP header, or make them all authenticate themselves with user names and passwords (or in some other way) in order to use your service.

Comment: Actually they send me username and key with their requests ( Every website has a unique username and password ) but I have a doubt that those web sites belong to the same user. it Is like he creates different accounts because there is a call limit by user

Comment: @lmanez Perhaps you should consider limiting the number of calls per client IP address as well as per user.

Comment: But what If I'm wrong and just those users use the same host server as you said ?

Comment: It's up to you. You can limit by username (but allowing one person to have multiple accounts and so get round your limit) or you can limit by IP address (possibly blocking different users on the same server). There's no technical way to set a limit per "real" user, because the reality of users is not something that can be determined technically.